# How to calculate LST using LANDSAT 9 Level 2 images in ArcGIS?

Tags: gis, arcgis, landsat

I am seeing various formulas on web on how to calculate LST such as

- LST=BT/1+w*(BT/p)*In(e)
- LST*0.00341802 +149.0
- LST= (BT)/(1+(λ*BT/14380)*ln(e)
  Which one is the correct formula to calculate LST for level 2 LANDSAT 9 images ?

Also, if you could help me if I have to use any of the above formula then,

- how to calculate BT from the images?
- what are the general values of w, p and e ?
- is ln is log ?

Thank you so much in advance for the help

I tried the old formula of converting to radiance, reflectance but it did not work. Then, after research found out that there is a totally different formula for calculating LST for level 2 images in LANDSAT 9.